# php curl image problem

Tags: php, curl, header

```
$ch = curl_init();
// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.hushmail.com/signup/turingimage?hush_domain=hushmail.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);
// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

result:

```
ÿØÿàJFIFÿş>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), default quality ÿÛC      $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342ÿÛC     2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222ÿÀ<�¯"ÿÄ  ÿÄµ}!1AQa"q2‘¡#B±ÁRÑğ$3br‚  %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ    ÿÄµw!1AQaq"2B‘¡±Á  #3RğbrÑ $4á%ñ&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚâãäåæçèéêòóôõö÷øùúÿÚ?ó I ”şôÊ1±Q2Ôö©£¥^:^Zûòä##ƒZvzÅœ7/¤[Ëƒ%À|¯jé¼)&9Öuí^ØİGGœIíÒ»Û±îÎ¤¢›µ×âqÚwI~$Òi©G§8#V¯†.,väñÒŸ™&—ˆ¼/{áû¨í¦+3É”y@œYúoö?Ù.ÿ´¾Óö¿èşV1»ıªŞ‡Ä/«Ïuu¬êÑZ”·hÀe®J8¥¹˜$hÒHÇ€£$×^áw6¥±fÛPû>Ÿuiöh_íıã®Y1ıÓÚ¥¶Ñnµˆ ÓÇÚÀ'Ëä>†»/ |/»¾   sª±·€ò#xÿ…v·š¿‡< mö[h”Ücˆ£v>ôªb’|´ÕØÜÕíÈµŸj^–İõÇ ‚Aö¤×JêR.«mh–ĞNŞZ@ŠkÙ+ğ)¹–Ùã˜Çæ"ù•…xm¬ZŒ·QÙÛ$Í:1)Cwâª…WQ^[ „¹µf¿„t}/SÔ® Ö®M¤i  u%¶’İ‡5¢Ç^ğ±²–ú;GÒÚ ç&ã' ¬Mzè}ªX6fBÌiÎ®"·>øãÄÚ’\ÜFWM‰‘ñû œEùy™WKŞl­cà©u2çT¶8¢]„®È{^k›K¿›Ïòí&o³ÿ®ÂŸ“ëé_Iêé¦7‡î,ZS¥[[J©¸cİ¯Öem]½}#PyìŒ¡_|œÊzÃ¸÷®Dî:Ue;œ©ƒïVWîŠ~¡u åÈ¹TÚò|Ò¨àŞØ«rXºGö8%‹æŞùÍiÓÂ?yƒµ–°ú…§†ÃYißeónA’åzb§ğŸ5æ‡u¥ÊƒdØ–9äÁ®NÒåÿ„bóVµÔ„RÆ|¹mÁÃ2ÿJÒøs8‹WºÜâÙŠŒğ®(kGcKZ2å{}çe¢k:J\êv¨ÑÙÜ ¹ `â¹'IšÛên’ÚGyZLp¸=3X¾Ò¡×üEqÜ®#ù™O'šé¦ÕÁ©i§Û*Í¦]ìï÷ˆ<íSk;!rr{±ÜËoêÚF©r–¡·³(e½t>ñTú¬:…½ÍÜ0j’ğÌä•P{Jç5bïR¹·µ!qÎ9œ{ñ[º«ƒá­3SÒ4Û2“¦GL•oÿ]å¶‡>)ÓP¼V¤:e¶¥àÍFY5q ÓõÁî°X¡÷¬MÃöWZa×´&-i¸‰¡=c?á^—%Ä1øi,’F¡ÄE‚¯ğ¸ô¯<øyçK>©c'6lşnãò©ìjêyvÖÌáëÙ¾èÔ|7—1Å-Ğ8˜ÈzĞW”ÛÇ`­z.™²ŠD‰³^ÍàßiqøVÚîyfçQ$„I´g¶~•y%YŒö.Má    d†EµGSµÔÉÈ>•. x?L¸ó´‘mç·Ê0ááUæø}á+»‡•î‹Hç,|şI©-şxf×R†òŞåÑ¢`Ê¢pFkÊ<®òbMwbxªËZ¿´‚ßG¸[rìD®{-AkáK–-GX¸…ï …if‹(’":GÕÓBŒ¥.h«Gó.1oU±sKÒá×ü_5ö±‹+'ÌèıÁ=+×ïm´[ÃQÙhšÔVÑ0¡`9ì+Ât¿^ivz…²ÇÂõv»J2WééTô5–mnÎİ±$Ê6ƒÁæ·ÄAÚì·MÉï±ï7ºXønÛJÔn¾×ö‰H–âC‚F:ıkÇZßÃ£Ä“i°™'³šdHïğcù½zWÆ{™ ğå„ J–“’=+Ä$ˆcd‘Ì§ï‚¸è{×*-Æ÷ÜÑñ.š^¿ue8›Cg#±ÍS_º*ÿ†,luoÛZê—FYLôôæ´µ1|/®Ë¶Ñ\Û¶L;Ÿ §c‘ZAêzXI%'¶2£ºŠãÆÛo–Aé]¯€.l&¼Õ µXîZÜù!y 1È¬K   <^ ·ñs™I6g¤iZ4¨.ô{UHíe'2;`cÔ¥QÔ‡ü#^¸Ó¬$ûEÄ­‹Ë”û«şÈ5‘«İê«nV]bIcU_İ—Á9ö¬XXIşmÓ¡r¦Ik;3}ˆa†K‰’QG8UI¯¥tİ2ïZéWNÑ·UuVÃ-|î–ú–=¥ñ·’,uáµ_¸ñGˆ ÖÚú{§[Ì`ç§#**Óu-fg%sÕÏÂ}nÔÕn×şÚÔ'á¨9‡\¼_ûi^;&¹ª6æ7÷<ÿ¬5oEñ.ªšÅ¯ªN"ßón“ŒUÒ¡YÅ¸Ì¨FvÑ…¨Èÿ5[H#‘¯â¹BnÌ„•WPø›q—+ù2^«$q¤Ÿ¼‡Şú×›İ_^ê±–K©deí’vŒõ«&Ñít{è¢µÔ’ùdŒHÒ'b{W\0ÑMsêÍT—,k~(oÌ÷:œ 'HP˜úSQİÜi÷Ş²··!»³Viİ€\=ê=7Ã·w7¶ğÜÚ\"Ü¡0‡ç8ãÔx‡Âš¯†îwÖì#ÄÀ„‘œ[®DùS/İÙw     }Ö«!ˆ(ÜXt=é¶·sXŞGunÛfˆîFô5¹‰ ƒÃwºRé±+Ü…e<ñëYi—wV77°ÄZŞÛkÿw=+,Eù5îi®¦¦¥â={ÅòÚÙ]În_~Ø—äÖ5ÕœöW’ZÏIãm¬Á¨â•á•e‰Ê:œ«)Á»]{H} ÇCñ\µíÍÆ%™¤Ã(n Wm¨4‘CÃÓµ#RºÔ.šŞhWªN<Çôæ™š–ºêÙxŠY!EL»ÉdUOøµCíF°Ç¸Iå ÀG$~5v$—ÄísyutÍ~¡F©ã§áW|75Û“²€]^ëF’Ú,“§Ø®?y±0?fÛ\,0H%´Y‘¸ÙùO·½U$$ã¥jÿhKÿÇØ6ÇåyşfvüÙÇ­i±è5Ê¶İ”VH€œ.UXaAıjÜ:z^YÂÑIK‡Ü¤ó…ç&³+Röf‹K²……t.Hç>´2¥~…kTCÈ–ía‰eßœfªàoÛ¸c8Í%hÃmhW%s*Jª­è )lqãÿ‚ÉŞĞµ«I'hï6ÊÊ:éÍhêŞ=íôÒè‘ƒ:%c“#jåÉ$ä’~´•èµ^òâÍ,u’\Á@ù3ßŠ¥­İi×MhÖº2ÂrùË?sT.n¥»I3n`¡AÆ8 *XaA$ô´¤²‡HµÒõ%š;‹‰´–¿s€ÃŞ¦ÑĞ[ÆºŠÏê7+øÆ ñ§6¥â9/fH–RÊqáxö®œ;½Ñ­>ÂÚk÷:f¡{r¶P©¼B&AôrîÇHÔ[LšÔËj.¤òî$“»íö­?‰¯æêL¥ZKÙ¶Œâ¸¶º™íÔ·î‘‹*ú[ÇŞJKBÖªèÓÔ5=BÇS0AªÍ2Ù±    Uú/N*i|E¬ø†]ûQßoæ ­1áO©>•E_*+•Káğ|D4–Ô­ïs¿÷}3Ö¬ÙÂ`mkIMb(­De‰ê. ô²,í£ÚòGÎè£Ü¸=óB4V2 nó‘Ô×>&ü«QÇ{n4KkMÇQšó&í_lh • ÷æ¨¶«zÚPÓZv6‚O0F½Zş5³‡K×_N´R–Ñ*²©9Á#šÍÖí"³½Há\)…ıHæ¸bî•ÊDñ0Y© C]—º:øfÚ+X&V ûÙ 2úUÊ=Y¯Zéäc«H„ëĞj4ËHî¢˜É»äPF©Å\N¬5›wèÿÙ
```

however, if i go to https://www.hushmail.com/signup/turingimage?hush_domain=hushmail.com via browser

that's okay. it works, it shows the image. why doesn't php curl work? i just want to learn the reason...

Comment: Why are you downloading CAPTCHA images from hushmail.com?

Comment: it was just an example. i'm not downloading their captchas. i just wanted to use it as a sample to show you. everythings okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the correct image data, cURL worked perfectly.

What you're missing is a content-type header to tell the browser you're sending an image and not text/html.

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
```

Comment: omg, you are perfect. i have spent my 15 hours on this issue. you solved my problem within the only 5 seconds. omg, thank you :) it works perfect..